# How to get data for react from php through json, preventing others from seeing these data?

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, json, database

I am getting from MySQL database data with PHP and converting them to JSON data so react get them.

#### PHP file:

```
    $trp = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM react_php");
        $rows = array();
        while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($trp)) {
            $rows[] = $r;
        }
        print json_encode($rows); //convert php data to json data
```

#### React file:

```
    useEffect(() => {
            axios
              .get("http://localhost/react-php-sql/server/get-data.php/")
              .then((res) => {
                setData(res.data);
              });
          }, [data]);
```

But the problem is that people can go to that URL and see these data. How can I prevent others from seeing them??

Comment: Look into authentication for APIs. Your PHP code will check that the user is authenticated and only return data if they are. Otherwise, it will return a 401 or 403 code. However, an authenticated user can still see the data. You can encrypt the data returned from PHP and decrypt in Javascript, but that can be overcome as well. In general, if you are sending any data to the client, you have to assume the user can access it and view it. So don't send anything you don't want the user to see.

Answer (score 0):

1. If your application is going to be deployed, all info related to project which is private such as API key, API end-point can be in env File (this file is not deployed with source code) and once you deploy your web info is configured at server, and no one can access it
2. If you're afraid of other developers who can access your API end-point through the browser developer tool(by inspect) you can make your API routes protected